# Upload video and use its URL

Tags: html, file, video, upload, host

I have a short video that I want to upload and use in the following code:

```
<video>
    <source src="video_url.mp4">
</video>
```

It's very simple but my problem is: I have no own file server. That's why I have to find a file-hosting provider where I can upload my video and use it from there.
But all they give me is just a download link for the video which is not what I need. What I need is a video-URL that directly plays the video.

For example like this one: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4

I have actually found a site that does what I need. This is the site: https://pomf.se

But unfortunately, that site is not available anymore.

Can anyone help me? How or where can I upload my video to get the required link-format? (I have the same problem with audio files)

Comment: Why not use Google Drive to upload your files and then use a direct link generator. Besides that, I don't know of any file hosting sites who provide direct hotlinking video files for free - some offer as a premium feature.

Comment: Google Drive doesn't give me the required video-link format either. And I want it to be all free.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use YouTube? You can create unlisted videos so they don't show up to the general public (they aren't public though). Other options could be Dropbox or S3 for inexpensive ways to host the videos yourself. Fact is, its storage space.. and that isn't free.

Comment: adding a youtube video link to <source src=""> won't work, I guess. But I haven't tried Dropbox, might do it now.